# Counting characters not working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=getlength("Hello",10);
    printf("%d",x);
}
int getlength(char line[],int limit)
{
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<limit-1 && line[x]!=EOF && line[x]!='\n';++x)
    printf("%c",line[x]) ;
    printf("\n");
return x;
}
```

So this code seems to output this:
    Hello%d then it outputs on a new line 9

What I don't understand is where the %d came from and how length of Hello%d is equal to 9

If anyone can explain I'd be happy.

Comment: Replace `EOF` with `'\0'`, which marks the end of a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.But I want to understand something.Isn't EOF also the end of the string? I think I misunderstood something.Thanks anyways :D.I appreciate your help.

Comment: `EOF` is defined to be negative, `'\0' == 0`

Comment: I think I'll google for these stuff.Thanks again :D

Comment: The marker for an end of a file has to be some byte that *cannot* appear in the data, otherwise you couldn't tell whether you had read that byte of data or found the end of a file. The marker for an end of a string must be something that *can* appear in the data, otherwise you couldn't store it in an array of characters.

Comment: Thanks people.Now I think I understand how this works. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Please trash that horrific `for`-statement and replace it with `int x = -1; while(line[++x] >= ' ' && x < limit); return x;`.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Thanks but I'm not looking into technicalities.I'm on my beginning to the journey of C :D

Comment: `EOF` is a (non-character) value returned by `getchar()`, `fgetc()` and friends to indicate that there was no input to be returned, either because you've hit the End Of the File (thus "EOF") or because there was an error. The value `EOF` is normally not stored anywhere; it's just returned by certain functions and then tested for.

Comment: `int main()` should be `int main(void)`. And you're calling `getlength` before its declaration is visible; either swap the definitions of `main` and `getlength`, or add a prototype for `getlength`.

Comment: Thanks Keith.The thing is I'm still in the beginning of everything(First chapter in the C book)
I added a prototype for them after I got a warning :D
And I understood the EOF.Thanks for further clarification :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character string in C is terminated with a null character, `'\0'`.  Change your `for` loop to test for the null character instead of `EOF`:

```
for (x=0; x < limit - 1 && line[x] != '\0' && line[x] != '\n'; ++x)
```

A function uses the constant `EOF` to signal the end of a *file*, but it's not used to terminate strings.  That's because binary files can contain (unsigned) characters with values from 0 to 255.  In order for a function to signal end-of-file, it must return a value that *cannot* appear within the file.  Every implementation I've seen uses `EOF` = -1, because unsigned characters can *never* be negative.

A string, on the other hand, can only contain valid (unsigned) characters, so it *can't* use `EOF` to mark its end.  Instead, it uses `'\0'`, which is equivalent to the integer 0 and is a vailid—but unprintable—character.

A *very* common pitfall for programmers is to forget this, and either neglect to terminate a string with a null character (in which case a program will often scan past the end into invalid memory), or to try to manipulate strings that contain binary data (which sometimes includes a null character and terminates the string unexpectedly).

Comment: The standard specifically requires `EOF` to be negative. The specific value is implementation-defined, but `-1` seems to be universal, or nearly so.

Answer (score 0):

You `for` loop just counts to 9 as it never finds a EOF or a newline in the string "Hello".

The string "Hello" is terminated with a null character `'\0'`, so change a part of for loop to `line[x]!='\0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the NUL character value:

```
int getlength(char line[],int limit)
{
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<limit-1 && line[x]!='\n' && line[x]!='\0'; ++x)
    {
        printf("%c",line[x]) ;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Don't compare a stored character to `EOF`, which is a non-character value used by certain input functions to indicate there's no more data to be read. And don't refer to the null character as NULL, since `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant (you got that right in the code, but mentioned "NULL" in the introductory sentence).

Comment: Your right... I copied the original code too fast, a character value cannot be -1.

Comment: Actually it can; if plain `char` is signed, then `-1` is a value `char` value. It *doesn't* denote end-of-file or anything similar; it's just another character value -- which is why you shouldn't try to compare it to `EOF`.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Thanks for your first comment. As `ch = getchar()` stores character one by one from input buffer to `ch`, Is it right to test a while loop as: `while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)`, where `ch` is a `char` type`?

Comment: @haccks: No. `getchar()` returns a result of type `int`; you need to store it in an `int` object if you want to be able to distinguish between `EOF` and a valid `char` value that might be stored as `0xff` or `-1`. See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) question 12.1.

Comment: @haccks: What?? `char` and `int` are distinct types.

Comment: @KeithThompson; sorry, if `ch` is of `int` type, then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32435/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-haccks)

Answer (score 0):

The length of 'Hello' is 5. My hunch is you are reading those characters from the stack frame.
You are reading from location even after 'hello' on the stack. This is what is there on the stack.
Probably from the '%d' in the printf.

Comment: Nah it got fixed.I should have used \0 instead of EOF :D